# Should a form controller include multiple inputs controllers

Tags: php, controller

I am wondering what is the proper way to validate a form that includes multiples types of inputs.

Should the form be a sequence of instructions that validate each input one by one :

```
class FormController{    

    function validateForm(){

            if(!$_POST['post_input_name']) return $error;

            if(!$_POST['post_input_birthday']) return $error;
    }
}
```

or should the form controller include one controller per input?

```
class FormController{    

    function __construct($input_name_controller, $input_birthday_controller){
            ....
    }

    function validateForm(){

            $this->getInputNameController()->validate($_POST);

            $this->getInputBirthdayController()->validate($_POST);
    }
}
```

My guess is that the second solution is better because generic fields controllers could be reused in other types of form and the code syntax seems more readable to me this way.

Any opinion on this is welcome. Thank you

Comment: Controllers are typically just glue. They're rarely ever reusable. Attempting to make them more generic and reusuable usually means you are trying to create an abstraction to solve a completely different problem than what a controller was meant to solve. For example, validation can be a completely separate abstraction from your controller. It need not be exclusive to the controller method's code.

Answer (score 0):

I started working with OpenCart about a week ago and all of its controllers have code like

```
...

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
...
```

so i think your first solution takes place to be

Answer (score -1):

Use a validation library like [valitron](https://github.com/vlucas/valitron) or [validation](https://github.com/werx/validation).

Comment: The point of the question is not use a third party library but to get the best practice using controllers for form validation.

Comment: I don't understand the point nor the best practice you are suggesting here.